# Determine connection speed of USB Tethering

Tags: 12.04

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and I need to connect to a network through USB tethering. Is there any command or tool to determine the network speed with which I am connected?

I used the command

ethtool eth0 | less

ethtool eth0 | grep -i speed

which provided results for LAN connection, but it does not detect the tethering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The USB thetering is unlikely named eth0 (which would normally be your standard network - ethernet port)

run:

```
ifconfig
```

there you can see all of your networking "devices".
try each of it with the ethtool then it should work.

My favorite tool to measure network speed live is nload. Install it with

```
sudo apt-get install nload
```